# How to set height in Android grid programmaticaly according to width?

Tags: android, layoutparams

I have gridview which contains 2 columns. The width is set to fill available space. 
I need height to be set to specific size according to width, because in every screen the width dimension is different, I can't set height in xml as constant. I need to set ratio, so height should be about 1.5 * width.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Height, but you want to get Width First.

You told 2 columns of grid so understand phone half of your phone width

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int imgWidth = display.getWidth() / 2;
int imgHeight = (int)(imgWidth * 1.5f);
```

You get height of that.Now you can set your Grid View Width and Height

```
LayoutParams lp = HERE_YOUR_VIEW.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = imgWidth;
lp.height = imgHeight ;
HERE_YOUR_VIEW.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: I needed to change to DisplayMetrics so it could work in adapter, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: @kodw you can pass width in your adapter, so you can set easily width and height your grid view.

Comment: do you have any example? I have tried convertView.getWidth(), but it did not worked.